# Rails 4, New App: Why do tests run in development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have simple, new Rails 4 app which clobbers the development database when I run `rake test:units`, even though I've set the RAILS_ENV in test_helper.rb. I wouldn't have expected that. Here are the simple steps to reproduce it.

I have Ruby 2.0.0p247 and Rails 4.0.1.

```
rails new foo
rails generate scaffold gadget
rake db:migrate
```

I edit test/models/gadget_test.rb to look like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class GadgetTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the env" do
    assert_equal "test", Rails.env
  end
end
```

and I have edited the first line of test/test_helper.rb from

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
```

to be

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
```

Even so, when the tests invoke `rake test:units` it fails:

```
  1) Failure:
GadgetTest#test_the_env test/models/gadget_test.rb:5]:
Expected: "test"
  Actual: "development"
```

With older (Rails 3) apps I've set up, I could count on this defaulting to the test environment. What am I missing?

Comment: When i was having this issue changing `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"` to `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"` fixed it. Are you sure your test_helper is being loaded by `rake test:units` ?

Comment: I would think `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"` is being called too late, Rails may have already cached the value of Rails.env?

Comment: Does `RAILS_ENV=test rake test:units` work as expected?

Comment: @j_mcnally, I am sure the test_helper is being called. To confirm, I put `raise "testhelper"` at the begging of that file. It raised the error before any tests ran. Also, running the command prefixed with `RAILS_ENV=test` definitely works right.

Comment: see `http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/env/class` it seems to cache the value as @_env if there is a call to env before you set ENV["RAILS_ENV"] it may cache development as the value in a mutable way.

Comment: @j_mcnally, you are getting me so close to an answer! What I've discovered is that application.rb has this line

    Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

it is setting the cached value of env before it gets to my line of code. I'm not sure how to rearrange things so they play together nicely, but I'm going to try a few things. If you have any ideas, feel free to suggest.

Comment: Even switching that line to Bundler.require(:default, ENV['RAILS_ENV']) doesn't seem to remedy the problem. Something else has to be invoking Rails.env, but I am unsure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer: there was a stray `export RAILS_ENV="development"` in a shell script referenced by my profile. So this is a seat-to-keyboard interface failure, directly from Oct 31, 2013 in this thread: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7175

All you need to do is take that out and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 6):

Mystery solved, with a big tip of the hat to j_mcnally!

To force the Rails env to "test" in Rails 4 (and probably much earlier), it no longer suffices to change the first line of the test_helper.rb to

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
```

This fails to reset the cached value of Rails.env, but if you invoke

```
Rails.env = "test"
```

It will reset the cached value properly. That said, there are other places where Rails.env is being invoked already, otherwise the cache wouldn't be set. One obvious one is bundler setup in application.rb, where it has `Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)` and changing that to `Bundler.require(:default, ENV['RAILS_ENV'])` (to avoid setting the cache) still indicates that other places in the initialization must also be invoking Rails.env. The significance of all of that is that some of the setup is going to think it's running in development and then the tests will run in the "test" environment.

Net answer: I have a way to get what I want, but there may still be some danger spots lurking out there.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR ensure that `require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'` line is not commented out in `config/application.rb`

---

I had the same problem, was trying out Minitest as a replacement for TestUnit, and generated Rails application without it (`rails new foobar --skip-test-unit`), but Minitest still uses test task from rails.

And I had the following code in the `config/applicaiton.rb`:

```
# require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

As j_mcnally and Fitter Man pointed out, the problem is that `Rails.env` caches its value before `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` got set, in my case it is getting called inside `Rails.groups`.

Trying to find in Rails sources how it sets proper `test` env when calling rake task, I found  that it does so in the `rails/test_unit/railtie.rb` which got commented out.

So the solution was as simple as uncommenting `require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'` line.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there shouldn't be any reason to have to force the `Rails.env` to the test. So if you're test are running in the wrong env there is something setting the env somewhere in your code.

For me it was caused by env export I didn't realize someone had placed on the first line of an `.rvmc` file for the app.

Removing that `export RAILS_ENV=development` line from that file and restarting terminal fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes, there was a stray export (see my answer from 9/4/14).